# как сделать замещение ссылки

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, django

Делаю сайт для себя и наткнулся на одну проблему. При попытки сделать переход по ссылке у меня появилась проблема. Когда кликаю на кнопку происходит переход на другую вкладку но когда я пытаюсь перейти на прошлую вкладку ссылка меняется но сама вкладка нет.Видео самой проблемы: https://yadi.sk/i/pAbBuTNxIqXfvg

*url папка приложения:*

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^about_us/',views.about_us,name='about_us'),
    url(r'^Conntact_data/$',views.Conntact_data,name='Conntact_data'),
    url(r'^Orders/$',views.Order,name='Order'),
]
```

*url папка проекта:*

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url 
from misite.views import home,about_us,Conntact_data,Order

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'home/', include('misite.urls')),
    url(r'about_us/', include('misite.urls', )),
    url(r'Conntact_data/', include('misite.urls', )),
    url(r'Order/', include('misite.urls',)),
]
```

*views папка:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Order

from .models import comment

def home (request,):
    return render(request, 'Web/home.html')

def about_us (request,):
    return render(request, 'Web/about_us.html')

def Conntact_data (request,):
    return render(request, 'Web/Conntact_data.html',)

def Order(request,):
    latest_orders_list = Order.object.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    return render(request, 'Web/Order.html', {'latest_orders_list': latest_orders_list})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Утята-Гусята</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name= content>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/reset.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}"class="h_logo" alt="Утята-Гусята" title=""></a>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main_nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="home/">Какие виды птиц у нас есть</a></li>
                    <li><a href=" about_us/ ">Об нас</a></li>                   
                    <li><a href='Conntact_data/'>Контактные данные</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Заказать птиц.html">Заказать птиц</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header><!-- Header End -->
```

*template страницы из который не получается произвести переход обратно*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Утята-Гусята</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name= content>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/reset.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}"class="h_logo" alt="Утята-Гусята" title=""></a>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main_nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="home/">Какие виды птиц у нас есть</a></li>
                    <li><a href=" about_us/ ">Об нас</a></li>                   
                    <li><a href='Conntact_data/'>Контактные данные</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Заказать птиц.html">Заказать птиц</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header><!-- Header End -->
```

Comment: 1. в Django 3.0 точно можно не использовать регулярки для парсинга путей. 2. из документации о `url`: This function is an alias to `django.urls.re_path()`. It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release, так что меняем на `path`. 3. Опишите проблему подробнее, а именно нужно приложить view для тех страниц, о которых вы говорите, а также ожидаемый результат

Comment: Я посмотрел "видео-доказательство", которые вы приложили. И, честно говоря, не понял, почему у вас так странно работают ссылки. Можно посмотреть template первой страницы, показанной на видео?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, ну все стало понятно. Так сайты на Django не пишутся. Вместо 
`<li><a href=" about_us/ ">Об нас</a></li>` нужно указывать пути на `view` url, который у вас есть. Итого, в шаблоне вам нужно поменять так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Утята-Гусята</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name= content>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/reset.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}"class="h_logo" alt="Утята-Гусята" title=""></a>
            <nav>
                <ul class="main_nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href=" {% url 'home' %}">Какие виды птиц у нас есть</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about_us' %}">Об нас</a></li>                   
                    <li><a href="{% url 'Conntact_data' %}">Контактные данные</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'Order' %}">Заказать птиц</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header><!-- Header End -->
```

Это должно сработать, если у вас только 1 приложение, где имена не конфликтуют. Иначе нужно будет еще указать `app_name`. 
Также советую последовать моим рекомендациям, которые я указал в первом комментарии. 
Все это должно сработать

Comment: хорошо, спасибо работает